# YQL: How to use key in yql v1/yql/* rest api call?

Tags: geocoding, yql, reverse-geocoding, yahoo-api

I am using yahoo's `yql` for doing reverse gecoding. As per yahoo documentation yql provides 100000 request per day, but for this yahoo needs an api key. I have created an application in yahoo and have it's consumer key and secret but I don't know where to place this key in yql v1/yql/* reset api call to increase the limit.

Please guide me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [OAuth1](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/about.html) to be able to use you *consumer_key* and *consumer_secret*.

Once you acquire **access_token** and **access_token_secret**, you will be able to query data as an authenticated user

If by any chance, you're working with **python**, i've made a library called [yahoo-oauth](https://github.com/josuebrunel/yahoo-oauth) to easily use ***OAuth1*** with **YQL**.

Hope it answers your question